# link function in .a into .so

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, ld

I have wrote a shared *libA.so*. My program *P* will dynamic load *libA.so* (uses dlopen, dlsym...).

Here's my problem:

In *libA.so*, I have to use functions (such as *fun1()*) in a static *libB.a*, but *libB.a* is not compiled with `-fPIC`, and I can't recompile *libB.a*, so I can't link *libB.a* into *libA.so*.

I have tried link *libB.a* into *P* (with -Wl,--whole-archive), in order to let dynamic loader link *fun1()* into *libA.so* when it is loaded. However, that doesn't work. And I'm pretty sure that *fun1()* is in *P* (I checked it with: `nm P | grep "fun1"`).

How can I do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Error message: `P: symbol lookup error: ./mylib/libA.so: undefined symbol: fun1` and nm output: `nm P | grep "fun1"
0000000000510f76 T fun1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to link `libB.a` into `P`, so that the functions are available to `libA.so` when it is loaded by `P`, you need to compile `P` with the `-rdynamic` option.